# Strange issue binding events with backbone, "this" is not being updated

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this, dom-events

I had a strange issue working with backbone and binding events. I'll see if I can explain it in a clear way (it's a cropped example...)

In a view, I had the following code in the initialize method

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(options) {
    //[...]
    this.items = [];
    this.collection.on('reset', this.updateItems, this);
    this.fetched = false;
  },

  render: function() {
    if (!this.fetched) {
      this.collection.fetch();  // fetch the collection and fire updateItems
      return this;
    }
    this.$el = $('#my-element');
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.items));
  },

  updateItems: function() {
    this.fetched = true;
    this.loadItems();
    this.render();   // call render with the items array ready to be displayed
  }
}
```

The idea is that I have to fetch the collection, process the items (`this.loadItems`), and then I set `this.$el`.

The problem I was facing, is that inside `updateItems`, I couldn't see any property added after the binding (`this.collection.on`...)

It seemed like the binding was done against a frozen version of the view. I tried adding properties to test it, but inside `updateItems` (and inside render if being fired by the collection reset event) I could not see the added properties.

I solved it binding the collection just before fetching it, like this:

```
  render: function() {
    if (!this.fetched) {
      this.collection.on('reset', this.updateItems, this);
      this.collection.fetch();
      return this;
    }
```

But it's a strange behavior. Seems like when binding, a copy of 'this' is made, instead of a reference.

Am I right? or there's anything wrong I'm doing?

Comment: You should use [this.setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) instead of `this.$el = ...` but I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Can you show where/how you create the instance of MyView?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I'm trying to reproduce the issue with a complete example starting from scratch, couldn't achieve so far, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your binding in the initialization phase of your collection view:

```
// View of collection
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('reset', this.updateItems);
}
```

now when fetch is finished on the collection **updateItems** method will be invoked.
Of course you need to bind the model and view before doing this:

```
var list = new ListModel();
var listView = new ListView({model: list}); 

list.fetch();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, that's the first thing I tried to do (check my example), but apparently Y stumbled across some strange behaviour, I'll try to reproduce it